# Does Makefile variable affect global variable?

Tags: variables, makefile

======================
Makefile 
======================

```
BOARD ?= JENNIC
```

Does that mean global variables `BOARD` and `JENNIC` are defined?

Comment: It's local, and means "if BOARD is undefined, define as string JENNIC". Read the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: What do you mean by "global"?  There are several things you *could* mean, and the answer is different for some of them than for others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a makefile as so:

```
BOARD1 ?= foo
BOARD2 = foo
BOARD2 ?= foobar   #will have no effect as BOARD2 is already set...

all:
    echo BOARD1 is $(BOARD1)
    echo BOARD2 is $(BOARD2)
```

without `BOARD1` or `BOARD2` being set anywhere else in the makefile or environment, it will output `BOARD1 is foo` and `BOARD2 is foo`

if on the other hand, you set the environment variable (using export) then make will use the value of the set environment variable.

```
> make
BOARD1 is foo
BOARD2 is foo
> #override the bash variables, note the use of export here...
> export BOARD1=bar
> export BOARD2=bar
> make
BOARD1 is bar
BOARD2 is foo
> # in this case the MAKE version of BOARD2 is overridden
> # but BOARD1 is not overridden (due to the ?=), so it uses the bash
> # value.
> # But, the bash values of the variables are not overridden by the makefile:
> echo BOARD1 is $BOARD1
BOARD1 is bar
> echo BOARD2 is $BOARD2
BOARD2 is bar
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your help